# Time zone mismatch in SQL Server

Tags: reactjs, sql-server, asp.net-core-webapi

When attempting to store date and time in a SQL Server table, the time does not correspond with the local time zone. What should I do to rectify the time?
Here is the code I've used.

```
public class Stage1Model
{
    
    [Key]
    public int JobID { get; set; }
    public int EmpID { get; set; }

    public string? CustomerName { get; set; }
    public string? OrderDetails { get; set; }
    public DateTime DispatchDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreateDateTime { get; set; }// this is where I take time for sql
    public string S1Status { get; set; }
   
}
```

This is my model

```
[EnableCors("AllowAll")]
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class OrderTrackingController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly ITracking _tracking;

    public OrderTrackingController( ITracking tracking)
    {
        _tracking = tracking;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> AddEntity([FromBody] Stage1Model model)
    {
        if (model == null)
        {
            return BadRequest("Invalid data");
        }
        model.CreateDateTime = DateTime.UtcNow;

        await _tracking.AddEntity(model);

        // Return the model with CreateDateTime converted to local time
        model.CreateDateTime = model.CreateDateTime.ToLocalTime();
        return Ok(model);
        //return CreatedAtAction(nameof(GetEntityById), new { id = model.Id }, model);
    }
}`
```

This is my controller
Response body
Download

```
{
  "jobID": 5,
  "empID": 12,
  "customerName": "hello",
  "orderDetails": "pan",
  "dispatchDate": "2023-11-23T06:49:03.367Z",
  "createDateTime": "2023-11-23T12:19:29.2882111+05:30",
  "s1Status": "completed"
}

Response headers
 content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8 
 date: Thu,23 Nov 2023 06:49:29 GMT 
 server: Kestrel
```

This is my API result where the times is taken as 'date: Thu,23 Nov 2023 06:49:29' GMT from Response headers in SQL Server table but my expected time is in Response body as "createDateTime": "2023-11-23T12:19:29.2882111+05:30" which is not taken into account by the SQL Server.

Comment: Whose "local time zone"? The web client's? The web API's? The SQL Server's? You seem to be using `DateTime` structs in .NET and haven't mentioned what you're using in SQL Server. If time zones and offsets are important to your application have you considered using [`DateTimeOffset`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset) in .NET and [`datetimeoffset`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetimeoffset-transact-sql) in SQL Server?

Comment: It's best practice to store `DATETIME`s in the database using UTC, rather than a specific time zone. You can then convert to local in your display layer. in SQL Server you can use GETUTCDATE() to reference the current date and time in UTC.

Comment: @PatrickHurst no it's *not*. That loses vital information (the offset) and assumes that can never change. In countries that use summer time the offset changes twice a year though, and a country's DST rules can change at any time.

Comment: First of all, there's no real confusion - the two time instants are *the same*. Second, JSON specifies that [dates should be in ISO8601 format](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7493#section-4.3), not `Thu,23 Nov 2023 06:49:29 GMT`. If you use `datetimeoffset` in the database, use `DateTimeOffset` in C# as well.

Comment: The discrepancy is caused by the code, not SQL Server. `DateTime` has no offset, only a Kind that can be `UTC`, `Local` or `Unspecified`. `UTC` is clear but `Local` and `Unspecified` are ambiguous - local for whom? And what actual offset does `Local` specify? When you load a `datetime` from the database there's nothing to indicate whether that time is UTC or not, so `Unspecified` is used. It's your own code that changes the DateTime kinds, not SQL Server

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos using UTC does not truncate the offset - UTC has NO offset, ever. It is not affected by DST or any other time zone changes. You'll notice I specifically call out `DATETIME` not `DATETIMEOFFSET`.

Comment: You missed the point. I didn't say truncate, I said `lose information`. If you use UTC, you lose the offset information. And yes, you're very much susceptible to DST changes because people record their *local* times, in their local timezone. If the offset changes, the UTC equivalent of that local time also changes. If you don't even know what the original offset was, you have no safe way of converting to the new offset. [Falsehoods programmers believe about time](https://gist.github.com/timvisee/fcda9bbdff88d45cc9061606b4b923ca) contains at least a couple of issues with UTC

Comment: @PatrickHurst it's not just DST either - what if you travel to another country? Outlook used to be notorious for first, not changing meeting times when you traveled to another country and once that was fixed, adjusting *your home country meetings*, not just the ones in the new country. That's why applications that care about time use the IANA timezone names like `Europe/London` or `Europe/Berlin`, not `+00:00` or `01:00`, or `02:00`. They store `17:00 Europe/London` not `17:00 +01:00`.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos That's why it's best practice to always record a `DATETIME` in UTC. There is **no** offset for UTC, it never changes, and it's never 'local'. It doesn't matter what country or time zone you are in, or move to, UTC is ALWAYS 00:00.

Comment: You didn't read either what I wrote or the `Falsehood` article. I gave some very common cases where the UTC time changes. I'm not talking about UTC's offset, but the actual time you'd record as UTC The `01:00Z` time you record today may have to change to `02:00Z` in 2 months if your local offset changes. Otherwise you'll lose your flight. That's not a contrived example either. Not only did Russia changed DST rules twice in less than 5 years, Egypt announced a change of DST rules in 2015 only a couple of weeks before the change

Comment: A cursory scan of your document doesn't seem to offer an incidence where UTC is different from UTC.

Comment: And that's not what I'm talking at all, or ever said in the comments. That's what you keep reading, for whatever reason. I guess you weren't one of the developers that had to ensure Egypt's DST changes didn't strand people at airports. Suffice to say that your flight is never published in UTC, it's published in the airport's timezone using the IANA timezones.

Comment: You're completely missing the point. `DATETIME` does not contain an offset, ever. It cannot. If you are going to use `DATETIME` it is best practice to use UTC in the `DATETIME`. It is **BETTER** to use `DATETIMEOFFSET`, it is a more precise data type, which is the entire reason for it to exist, but that is completely irrelevant from the subject of `DATETIME`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256076/discussion-between-patrick-hurst-and-panagiotis-kanavos).

Answer (score 2):

To avoid confusion that can arise from local time zone differences, store dates and times in UTC format in the database. When you need to display the time to the user, convert the UTC time to the local time zone at the application level. This is what you're doing in your controller when you call `ToLocalTime()`. However, this conversion should typically be done when retrieving data for display, not before storing or after adding it to the database.

you could try below modified code:

```
public class Stage1Model
{
    public DateTimeOffset DispatchDate { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset CreateDateTime { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> AddEntity([FromBody] Stage1Model model)
{
    if (model == null)
    {
        return BadRequest("Invalid data");
    }

    // Set the CreateDateTime with the current UTC time and the local offset
    model.CreateDateTime = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;

    await _tracking.AddEntity(model);

    // No need to convert CreateDateTime to local time here,
    // since DateTimeOffset keeps track of the time zone.

    return Ok(model);
}
```

In SQL Server table check it has columns defined with the `datetimeoffset` data type to accommodate this.when you read the `DateTimeOffset` from the database to display it to the user, you should convert it to the user's local time zone. This conversion should be done at the application level, typically in the presentation logic of your application.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this exactly the answer you are looking for, but both of those timestamps are the same. Both timestamps contain time zone identifiers which gives you the calculation you need to convert the times between time zones.

`2023-11-23T06:49:03.367Z` is the local time in a UTC+0:0 time zone (the Z indicates UTC).

`2023-11-23T12:19:29.2882111+05:30` is the local time in a UTC+5:30 time zone (+5:30 indicates the time zone).

Notice that if you take 5h 30m (+5:30) from `2023-11-23 12:19:29` you get `2023-11-23 6:49:29` which gives you the UTC(+0) time zone local time.

I think the above answers your question hopefully.

However a second issue might arise when storing these timestamps in the database. Depending on the engine, it might not store the value with it's appropriate time zone identifier.

Therefore storing `2023-11-23T12:19:29.2882111+05:30` in the database and then retrieving it might return `2023-11-23T12:19:29.2882111` which DateTime won't know what the time zone is from that string value.

That value could instead mean `2023-11-23T12:19:29.2882111` UTC which is actually `2023-11-23T17:49:29.2882111+5:30` in UTC(+5:30).

Which is why in general, when storing values in the database you store it as it's UTC value (as you have done in the post). Then when you retrieve it you can convert it to local time, knowing that the value is UTC.

Comment: If the column uses `DateTimeOffset` the offset is preserved. It's definitely *not* enough to store times as UTC. Offsets change regularly twice a year due to summer time rules and can also change unexpectedly if a country's DST rules change. If you only store UTC you won't be able to handle such changes. While the offset isn't enough, it's a *lot* better than no information at all

Comment: I'm pretty that is incorrect. Storing in UTC is always valid without time zone data. It is still your responsibility to write it as correctly UTC and read it knowing it is UTC. But if that is your convention, then it doesn't need any time zone data or offset. Perhaps it is safer to add it, but my answer is still correct provided you follow the convention - but isn't that true of all conventions?

Comment: That's an unsafe assumption, not convention, like assuming all text in a database and applications will use the same ASCII codepage (never mind assuming it's always Latin1). When you converted to UTC you lost the original timezone/offset. If that offset changes, the UTC value will be wrong. And in case you think that can't happen, it does, twice a year regularly and sometimes [abruptly with just a few weeks notice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time_in_Egypt). That's why flights are published and stored as local time *and* the IANA timezone name eg `Europe/Berlin`, not UTC

Comment: [Falsehoods programmers believe about time](https://gist.github.com/timvisee/fcda9bbdff88d45cc9061606b4b923ca). Notice how many falsehoods are about UTC and offsets. `The offsets between two time zones will remain constant.`, no, especially when they switch to summer time at different dates, eg US and Europe. `OK, historical oddities aside, the offsets between two time zones won’t change in the future.` no, it just takes a law or executive decision. Russia changed DST rules twice in a few years. `Changes in the offsets between time zones will occur with plenty of advance notice.` no, Egypt

Comment: `The local time offset (from UTC) will not change during office hours.` only if you assume nothing works at night, not even the cron jobs on your server. Now *that* would make for a great QA test. Or you have no presence in other countries. That's false for all ecommerce sites, airlines, airports, trains, shipping in general.

Comment: Panagiotis - your reasoning I understand. Your application is poor. You do realize that when you write a program you make a lot of assumptions about people following convention? Or do you suggest that we always store check bits along with our text values in the database in case someone saves a text value wrong?

Comment: You mean like the check digits in VAT, credit card, ticket and IBAN numbers? Or the BOM bytes in Unicode files? The CHECK constraints that ensure you don't insert garbage in fields? Would you accept losing your flight because a developer made an assumption? It's not about my reasoning, it's about how real applications on which people depend actually work. Yes, real applications add extra checks to avoid mistakes that would result in costly refunds.

Comment: That is exactly my point.. when you store the UTC date into the database you ensure you are storing a UTC value.. just adding the date time offset doesn't mean you stored the correct time.. what if in your code you got the source timezone wrong? The data would look valid but be incorrect. You can't prevent someone input misleading data. You could say we only ever want to add UTC values and always add the +0 identifier, that wouldn't stop someone getting a date from +1 and saying that is is utc.. therefore giving the wrong time. I'm not talking about whether the data is in the wrong format..